# Get xpath of a link in a webpage containing "sometext"

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I'm using scrapy (web crawling framework). Is there any way I can get the xpath of a certain element (containing "sometext") in a web page so I can extract elements with similar xpaths? I don't want my xpaths to be hardcoded because I will be crawling multiple websites.

I'm new to scrapy and I have been searching for days and I can't find anything :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to explicitly specify which element you want to scrape either you use `xpath` or `regular expression` or some library like `beautifulsoup`. One way of not explicitly specifying the `xpath` is to traverse the `DOM` and extracting the elements you need. But even in this case you need some kind of mechanism for identifying the elements you want to scrape. Also you should write different spiders for scraping different websites. Scraping multiple website with a single spider will make your task much harder and its not a good practice either.

For deploying and running spiders you can look into [scrapyd](https://scrapyd.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know that I should use different spiders for different websites. One question, can I run multiple spiders simultaneously? If so can you please tell me how or at least point me in the right direction?

Comment: @salmanwahed Scrapy can find plain text without needing to specify the element it's in. As for different spiders for different websites you are being too prescriptive by saying "it's not good practice". In general I agree that websites can need their own spider but it's an engineering decision on a case by case basis.

Comment: @Steve I see you missed several points of the answer. what are you doing in your answer is also using xpath and searching text. this can be done in many other ways also.

Comment: @salmanwahed, My bad, I misread the question. Edit your answer and I'll remove the down vote.

Comment: @salmanwahed StackOverflow wont let me remove the down vote unless the answer is edited. You don't have to change anything in particular, just enough to be accepted by this website.